# Insercion de campos generados dinámicamente en un formulario (Laravel)

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel-5

El problema es que requiero enviar datos a través de un formulario a un controlador en Laravel, con el envio de datos que se recogen de campos que están en el código HTML inicial no tengo ningún dilema, la cuestión es que hay campos que genero mediante JS (He intentado también con la librería JQuery), y cuando estos trato de recogerlos en el controlador, no aparecen, en el controlador (Para saber si estoy capturando el arreglo):

class ActivoController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request) 
    {

```
    return $request['tipoActivos'];

}
```

}

En la vista:

```html
@extends('templates.templateMain')

@section('registro')
    class="active"
@endsection

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    @include('alerts.errors')
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Recepción De Activo Fijo</h1>
    </div>                                                           
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'activo.store', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
        <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label>Numero</label> 
                <input class="form-control" name="numeroDocumento" readonly value="{!!$numeroDocumento!!}" align="right">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Fecha</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fechaDocumento">                  
        </div>         
</div> 
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label>Nombre Del Encargado</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="empleado" placeholder="Elija una opción o ingrese el dato (Letras)" list="empleados">
        <datalist id="empleados">
            @foreach($empleados as $empleado)
                <option>{{$empleado->nombre}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </datalist> 
    </div>      
</div>
<br>             
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label>Proveedor/Contratista</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="proveedor" placeholder="Nombre (Letras)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label>Cédula o NIT</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="idProveedor" type="number" placeholder="Dato (Númerico)"> 
    </div>
</div>
<br>          
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="numeroFilas" id="numeroFilas" value="0">     
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table_striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                        <th>Activo</th>
                        <th>Cantidad De Activos</th>
                        <th>Valor Unitario</th>
                        <th>Localización</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Material</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody">
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" name="tipoActivo[]" placeholder="Ingrese o elija" list="tipoActivos">
                            <datalist id="tipoActivos">   
                                @foreach($tipoActivos as $tipoActivo)
                                    <option>{{$tipoActivo->nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </datalist>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" name="numeroActivos[]" type="number" placeholder="Dato númerico">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" name="valorActivo[]" type="number" placeholder="COP=>400000"> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Sede</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="sede[]" id="sede">
                                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Elija una opción</option>
                                    @foreach($sedes as $sede) 
                                        <option value="{{$sede->nit}}">{{$sede->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach 
                                </select>
                                <br>
                                <label>Espacio</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="espacio[]" id="espacio">  
                                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Elija una opción</option> 
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>  
                            </div> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" name="estado[]">
                                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Elija</option>
                                <option>Nuevo</option> 
                                <option>Usado</option>  
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" name="marca[]" placeholder="Ingrese o elija" list="marcas">
                            <datalist id="marcas">
                                @foreach($marcas as $marca)
                                    <option>{{$marca->nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </datalist>
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <input class="form-control" name="material[]" placeholder="Ingrese o elija" list="materiales"> 
                            <datalist id="materiales">
                                @foreach($materiales as $material)
                                    <option>{{$material->nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach   
                            </datalist>
                        </td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="crearSedes({{$sedes}});agregarFila();"></a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>  
                </tbody> 
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<br>             
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label>Modo de adquisición</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="modoAdquisicion">
            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Elija una opción</option>
            <option>Compra</option>
            <option>Donación</option>
            <option>Permutación</option>
            <option>Otro</option> 
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div> 
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label>Observaciones</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="observaciones" placeholder="Información opcional (Alfanúmerico)"></textarea>
        <p class="help-block" align="justify">Las observaciones son un campo opcional, el resto de campos son obligatorios.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label>Huella del encargado</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="huella_encargado" readonly placeholder="Pendiente" style="width:100px;height:100px">
        <p class="help-block" align="justify">Para terminar completamente el proceso de registro, usted deberá poner su huella en la aplicación de escritorio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        {!!Form::submit('Registrar', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

En el JS:

```js
var opcionesSedes = new Array();
    function dce(e){
        return document.createElement(e);
    }
    function alterarContador(operador){
        switch(operador) {
            case 0:
                var contador = parseInt( document.getElementById('numeroFilas').value ) + 1;
                document.getElementById('numeroFilas').value = contador;
            break;
            case 1:
                var contador = parseInt( document.getElementById('numeroFilas').value ) - 1;
                document.getElementById('numeroFilas').value = contador;  
            break; 
        }
    }
    function crearSedes(sedes){
        opcionesSedes= sedes.slice(); 
    }
    function eliminarFila(a){
        alterarContador(1);
        fila = a.parentNode.parentNode;
        fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);
    }
    function crearCelda(tipo){
        td = dce('td');
        var numeroFila = String(document.getElementById('numeroFilas').value);
        switch(tipo) {    
            case 0:
                input = dce('input');
                input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control'); 
                input.setAttribute('name', 'tipoActivo[]');   
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Ingrese o elija');
                input.setAttribute('list', 'tipoActivos');
                td.appendChild(input);
            break; 
            case 1: 
                input = dce('input');
                input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'numeroActivos[]');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Dato númerico');
                td.appendChild(input);
            break;
            case 2: 
                input = dce('input');
                input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'valorActivo[]'); 
                input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'COP=>400000');
                td.appendChild(input);
            break;
            case 3:
                div = dce('div');
                div.setAttribute('class', 'form-group');
                labels = dce('label');
                labels.innerHTML= 'Sede';
                selects = dce('select');
                selects.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                selects.setAttribute('name', 'sede[]');
                selects.setAttribute('id', 'sede');
                options = dce('option');
                options.setAttribute('value', '0');
                options.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
                options.setAttribute('selected', 'true');
                options.innerHTML = 'Elija una opción';
                selects.appendChild(options);
                for(var i=0; i < opcionesSedes.length; i++) {
                    optioni = dce('option');
                    optioni.setAttribute('value', opcionesSedes[i].nit );
                    optioni.innerHTML = opcionesSedes[i].nombre;
                    selects.appendChild(optioni);
                } 
                br = dce('br');
                labele = dce('label');
                labele.innerHTML = 'Espacio';
                selecte = dce('select');
                optione = dce('option');
                optione.setAttribute('value', '0');
                optione.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
                optione.setAttribute('selected', 'true');
                optione.innerHTML = 'Elija una opción';
                selecte.appendChild(optione);
                selecte.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                selecte.setAttribute('name', 'espacio[]');
                selecte.setAttribute('id', 'espacio'); 
                div.appendChild(labels);
                div.appendChild(selects);
                div.appendChild(br);
                div.appendChild(labele);
                div.appendChild(selecte);
                td.appendChild(div);
            break;
            case 4:
                select = dce('select');
                select.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                select.setAttribute('name', 'estado[]');
                option0 = dce('option');
                option0.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
                option0.setAttribute('selected', 'true');
                option0.innerHTML = 'Elija';
                option1 = dce('option');
                option1.innerHTML = 'Nuevo';
                option2 = dce('option');
                option2.innerHTML = 'Usado'; 
                select.appendChild(option0);
                select.appendChild(option1);
                select.appendChild(option2);
                td.appendChild(select);
            break;
            case 5: 
                input = dce('input'); 
                input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'marca[]');
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Ingrese o elija');
                input.setAttribute('list', 'marcas');
                td.appendChild(input);
            break; 
            case 6:
                input = dce('input');
                input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                input.setAttribute('name', 'material[]');
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Ingrese o elija');
                input.setAttribute('list', 'materiales');
                td.appendChild(input);
            break;
            case 7:
                a = dce('a');
                a.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
                a.setAttribute('onclick', 'eliminarFila(this)');
                td.appendChild(a);
            break; 
        } 
        return td;
    }
    function agregarFila(){
        alterarContador(0); 
        tbody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
        tr = dce('tr');
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(0));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(1));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(2));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(3));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(4));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(5));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(6));
        tr.appendChild(crearCelda(7));
        tbody.appendChild(tr);  
    }
```

Cabe mencionar que no tengo ningún problema para generar las filas (El JS funciona), mi problema radica en que no he encontrado la forma de capturar estos datos en el formulario.

Comment: ¿Cómo los estas enviando? No veo nada ahí que haga o pueda hacer que esos campos se envíen y por favor pon el código como texto, las imágenes son una mala alternativa

Comment: De acuerdo, fue un error mío, he editado la información, gracias por la recomendación